# Ошибка "No tests found" после добавления Multidex

Tags: android, multidex

После добавления Multidex перестали запускаться тесты через консоль. 
Если запускать из пакета или класса, то все работает. 
А через консоль нет. Само приложение собирается.

Часть logcat:

```
> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
01:55:57 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
01:55:58 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'YT9118WPMT' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:55:58 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:55:58 D/app-debug-androidTest.apk: Uploading app-debug-androidTest.apk onto device 'YT9118WPMT'
01:55:58 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'YT9118WPMT'
01:56:00 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug-androidTest.apk"
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug-androidTest.apk"' on 'YT9118WPMT' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug-androidTest.apk"
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug-androidTest.apk"' on 'YT9118WPMT' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:56:15 I/RemoteAndroidTest: Running am instrument -w -r   com.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner on D5803 - 6.0.1
01:56:15 V/ddms: execute: running am instrument -w -r   com.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
01:56:18 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
01:56:18 I/InstrumentationResultParser: test run failed: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError''
Starting 0 tests on D5803 - 6.0.1
Tests on D5803 - 6.0.1 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
01:56:18 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.AbstractParameterFactory
01:56:18 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
01:56:19 V/InstrumentationResultParser:
01:56:19 V/ddms: execute 'am instrument -w -r   com.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' on 'YT9118WPMT' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:56:19 V/ddms: execute: returning

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[D5803 - 6.0.1] FAILED
```

Часть build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use [`MultiDexTestRunner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/test/runner/MultiDexTestRunner.html), which is deprecated; use [`AndroidJUnitRunner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) instead.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#testing

---

Если по-русски: Не используйте устаревший [`MultiDexTestRunner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/test/runner/MultiDexTestRunner.html); вместо этого используйте [`AndroidJUnitRunner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html)

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: То же положение дел остается.
Я изначально использовал ```AndroidJUnitRunner```. Потом уже в ходе экспериментов пробовал ```MultiDexTestRunner```

Comment: Что - и ошибка та же самая?

Comment: Кстати нет. Появился java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Обновил вопрос. Это значит multidex-config.txt не корректный тогда?